# Called function returning blank value?

Tags: python, shell, tuples

I have a function called getHTML(URL) which returns a 1-tuple containing a string of the words on that web page. If I simply call getHTML in the shell directly, it works fine. However, when I try to call getHTML in another function, it returns a tuple containing a blank string. Here's the code:

```
def exampleFunction():
    return getHTML(input('Enter a URL: '))
```

Now in the shell, if I type exampleFunction() and enter a URL (string) when prompted, it simply returns:

```
('')
```

a blank string in a tuple. I have no idea why this isn't working. I'm also quite new to Python so please excuse me if this is a result of a trivial error I've made.

Also, the getHTML function code was given to us by the professor and it is quite long and complicated. It's guaranteed to be error-free, so I haven't posted it because I don't see the need to. Again, it works fine when I simply call it directly in the shell.

EDIT:

Here's an example of the output when I call it in the shell. First line is input, second is output:

```
getHTML('http://networks.cs.northwestern.edu/EECS110-s13/projects/project2/page3.htm')

('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\penguins, penguins, penguins! this webpage has penguins. page 1 page 2\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\')
```

Again, the code he gave us is massive and if I posted it here no one would read it. I did check, however, and he is using return rather than print.

Also, tell me if you can't access that URL and I'll try another.

Comment: You need to show the code for getHTML, or at least show the output of `getHTML(input('Enter a URL: '))`.  It is possible that getHTML is only printing its output and not returning it.

Comment: `"It's guaranteed to be error-free"` - Yep, that's what happens when you become a professor - you're suddenly unable to produce software bugs anymore!

Comment: I said that because it seems no other students have had a problem with this assignment. 

Also, is it at all possible that my version of IDLE is somewhat defective? I say this because I've had many minor issues all year, and I've had to correct them with inelegant workarounds. For example, if I type range(0,10) in the shell and hit enter, is it not supposed to return [0, 1, 2,..., 9]? It just returns exactly what I typed, "range(0,10)".

Comment: What happens if you actually do `getHTML(input('Enter a URL: '))` and then enter the same thing you're entering when you call `exampleFunction`?  Are you sure you're not entering an invalid URL or something like that?

Comment: @user3317405, you'd get `range(0, 10)` instead of a list if you're using Python 3. It's possible that the code provided by your professor only works correctly in Python 2. Try your code using Python 2.7 instead.

Comment: @BrenBarn I just tried doing that directly in the shell. Ended up with the same result: the tuple with the blank string. It seems the problem is involving the input() step then? It has to be, that's the only difference between the things that work and fail. I don't know why though.

Comment: Also, in Python 2.7 you'd generally want to use `raw_input` instead of `input`. The difference is that in Python 2, `input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(...))`.